# What do I have to do in this case: List<Sobject> or Sobject?

Tags: apex, list, sobject, bestpractice

I am beginner in Salesforce and I have to verify if the field `Order.ShippingCountry` is filled using the `OrderId`.

I would like to reuse this method below to fetch the `Order.ShippingCountry`. But I was wondering if it is a good practice to use `Order` as a return. Ideally, do I have to create another method to return a `List<Order>` ?

```
public class OrderSelector {

    public static Order getOrderAndOrderItemsById(Id orderId){

            return [SELECT Id,OwnerId,EffectiveDate,ShippingCountry,
                    AccountId,Account.Name
                    (SELECT Id, Quantity, UnitPrice, 
                     Product2.ProductCode,Product2.Name,Product2.Family
                     FROM OrderItems)
                    FROM Order
                    WHERE Id = :orderId];
        }}
```

Using the current version of the method above, my method will be like it:

```
public class ValidateOrder {

    public class ValidateOrderException extends Exception{}

    private static void validateShippingCountryByOrderId(Id orderId) {

          Order varOrder = OrderSelector.getOrderAndOrderItemsById(orderId);

          if(varOrder.ShippingCountry.isEmpty()){
            throw new ValidateOrderException(Label.InvalidateDeleteDocument);
          }
    }

}
```

Is my code following best practices? Or would it be better to apply `List<Order> varOder` ? Also, as a good practice, would it be better to create another method in `OrderSelector` class to fetch only the `Order.ShippingCountry` and not all these fields?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my experience, selector methods should, in general:

- accept collections as input and return collections as output. This avoids null checks.
- not be static as it facilitates mocking patterns such as ApexMocks which as you evolve your experience, you may come to favor

  ```
  public class OrderSelector {

    public Order[] getOrderAndOrderItemsById(Set<Id> orderIds){
        orderIds.isEmpty()
         ? new List<Order>()
         : return [SELECT Id,OwnerId,EffectiveDate,ShippingCountry,
                AccountId,Account.Name
                (SELECT Id, Quantity, UnitPrice, 
                 Product2.ProductCode,Product2.Name,Product2.Family
                 FROM OrderItems)
                FROM Order
                WHERE Id IN :orderIds];
    }}
  ```

If you follow the [Lightning Enterprise Architecture](https://www.packtpub.com/product/salesforce-lightning-platform-enterprise-architecture-third-edition/9781789956719) patterns, the method name would be changed to

```
selectByOrderIds(Set<Id> orderIds) or
selectById(Set<Id> orderIds) // less is more
```

as the method is part of an `OrdersSelector`, so by definition, you don't need to repeat `Order` in the method name.

You could also name it:

```
selectWithOrderItemsById(Set<Id> orderIds)
```

if you want to be clear that the return includes `OrderItems`

Comment: You said this have to return collections as output, but Is `Order[]` a collection? And could `Order[]` recieve more than one record?

Comment: `Order[]` is same as `List<Order>`; fewer characters to type :-)

Answer (score 2):

It depends. As written, if the user doesn't have access to the record, or the record Id is invalid, you'll get a "No rows for assignment". You might want more explicit error handling in this event.

```
public static Order getOrderAndOrderItemsById(Id orderId){
  try {
    return [SELECT Id,OwnerId,EffectiveDate,ShippingCountry,AccountId,Account.Name
             (SELECT Id, Quantity, UnitPrice, Product2.ProductCode,Product2.Name,Product2.Family
                 FROM OrderItems)
                FROM Order
                WHERE Id = :orderId];
    } catch(ListException e) {
      throw new CustomExceptions.InvalidIdOrInsufficientAccess(recordId);
    }
}
```

That aside, I would generally prefer accepting a list of Id values, and returning a list of Order records, because you'll need it more likely than not, and you'll avoid accidentally writing SOQL inside a for loop later down the line:

```
for(Order record: Trigger.new) {
  Order queriedRecord = OrderSelector.getOrderAndOrderItemsById(record.Id);
  // etc...
}
```